# Share de produto de loja virtual para o Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, html-meta-tag

Estou com problema pra fazer o share de um produto de uma loja virtual para o facebook.
Estou colocando as meta tags na página do produto:

```
<meta property='og:title'...
<meta property='og:url' ...
<meta property='og:site_name' ...
<meta property='og:type' content='website'/>
<meta property='og:image' ...    
<meta property='og:description' ...
```

E o script que uso para abrir a janela de share está assim:

```
$("#btn_facebook").bind('click', function (event) {
          var twtTitle = document.title;
          var twtUrl = location.href;
          var imagem = 'http://www.meusite.com.br' + $("#Share_Image").val();
          var twtLink = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + twtUrl;
          window.open(twtLink,'', '_blank', 'location=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes, width=575, height=520, fullscreen=yes, status=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no');                                    
});
```

Até abre a janela de share corretamente com a foto e descrição do produto, mas, quando clico em compartilhar, na postagem no facebook, vão todas descrições e texto, mas, a imagem não carrega e não aparece. Aparece apenas um quadro branco sem a foto que antes apareceu.

Alguém pode me ajudar a identificar esse problema ou tem alguma solução?
Obrigado,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Isto foi porque na altura havia um bug no `url scrapper` do Facebook.

A razão pela qual as imagens de apresentação (`og:image`) não estavam a aparecer nas publicações juntamente com o resto das informações (`og:title, og:descriptino` etc) foi devido a este bug.

Embora para algumas pessoas este bug possa ter desaparecido no final do próprio dia (30/04/2015) enquanto se tratava do mesmo, 
este erro foi totalmente corrigido e o [*ticket*](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140) dado como <kbd>**resolvido**</kbd> uns dias depois. Mais precisamente dia - 7 de Maio 2015: 
[**URL Scrapper Bug Status**](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140)

Answer (score 0):

Nesse exato momento o Facebook deve estar passando por algum problema. Tenho um site aqui que faz exatamente isso mas agora as vezes carrega e as vezes não. Esse site está a uns 2 meses online funcionando exatamente desse maneira que você mencionou. Mudando apenas o fato de no meu caso eu deixo a url https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=... no próprio href com um target _blank, o Facebook que se encarrega de abrir um popup.

Ps.: Em um outro caso o Facebook não exibia de jeito algum minha imagem setada na metatag, depois descobri que era a imagem que estava pesada que levava alguns segundos para ser carregada e por isso o Facebook não exibia. Tipo um timeout da requisição. Troquei por uma imagem leve e funcionou.

Comment: A imagem que estou tentando compartilhar tem apenas 13kb, então o problema não é o peso da imagem.

Comment: E com respeito à esta instabilidade temporária do facebook, acredito que não seja o caso, pois conheço diversos sites que estão funcionando.

Comment: Ainda ontem a imagem de compartilhamento do site voltou a funcionar, no meu caso...